# reshape dictionary by tuple keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keys as tuples that correspond to the order I would like to reshape them:

```
{(1, 2): 'red', 
 (3, 2): 'green', 
 (3, 1): 'orange', 
 (2, 1): 'blue', 
 (2, 2): 'yellow', 
 (1, 1): 'purple'}
```

The key should be reshaped into a nested dictionary based on the index of the tuple:

```
{1: 
    {1: 'purple',
     2: 'red'},
 2: 
    {1: 'blue',
     2: 'yellow'},
 3: 
    {1: 'orange',
     2: 'green'}
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempt at a solution?  Right now, this reads as a request for us to write this for you.

Comment: @KevinW  I have no idea how to do this, that's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> d = {(1, 2): 'red', 
...  (3, 2): 'green', 
...  (3, 1): 'orange', 
...  (2, 1): 'blue', 
...  (2, 2): 'yellow', 
...  (1, 1): 'purple'}
>>> r = {}
>>> for k in d:
...     r.setdefault(k[0], {})[k[1]] = d[k]
... 
>>> r
{1: {1: 'purple', 2: 'red'}, 2: {1: 'blue', 2: 'yellow'}, 3: {1: 'orange', 2: 'green'}}
```

This part:

```
r.setdefault(k[0], {})
```

returns `r[k[0]]` if it exists. Otherwise it assigns a new empty dict to `r[k[0]`] and returns that.

Let us call that returned dict "somedict". You have a normal dict assignment like this

```
somedict[k[1]] = d[k]
```

Comment: what's happening in `[k[1]] = d[k]`?

Comment: @MichalFrystacky it's not clear because it's all on one line, but setdefault returns the value of whatever key's passed in as the first argument. So since `k` is the pair of key values in `d`, it's the 1st item in the tuple of k, so the color

Comment: `r.setdefault(k[0], {})` seems to make a new dictionary based on the first value of the tuple, but I'm not sure what happens next.

Answer (score 1):

While I absolutely love John's approach, one can also code a bit more conservative:

```
for i,j in d:
    if i not in r:
        r[i] = {}
    r[i][j] = d[(i,j)]
```

which might be slightly easier to understand for someone else reading your code (or yourself next week ;).

Comment: In Python it's more usual to write `if i not in r:` - it means the same thing to Python